# Python - "'str' object does not support item assignment" Error Fix

Tags: python

So I've been following along some of the projects from the 'Big Book of Small Python Projects' by Al Sweigart and ive been attempting to follow along one of the projects, however Ive been stuck on this segment of code for a while now and was wondering if anyone could help. Anytime i run the code I keep getting an error on this line "WORDS[i] = WORDS[i].strip().upper()". It says "'str' object does not support item assignment" and I am unsure how to fix. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# Load the WORDS list from the text file
with open('sevenletterwords.txt') as wordListFile:
    WORDS = wordListFile.readline()
    for i in range(len(WORDS)):
        # Convert each word to uppercase and remove the trailing newline
        WORDS[i] = WORDS[i].strip().upper()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Is `WORDS` meant to be a single line?

Comment: `WORDS` is a string and cannot be assigned through indexing. Perhaps just use `WORDS.upper().strip()`, rather than the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `readlines`:

```py
with open('test.csv') as wordListFile:
    WORDS = wordListFile.readlines() # updated here
    for i in range(len(WORDS)):
        # Convert each word to uppercase and remove the trailing newline
        WORDS[i] = WORDS[i].strip().upper()
```

Here is an approach that uses a `lambda` function:

```py
with open('test.csv') as wordListFile:
    WORDS = wordListFile.readlines()    
    WORDS = list(map(lambda x: x.strip().upper(), WORDS))
    print(WORDS)
```